# Remove rows from matching athletes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a ufc dataset i am practicing on and want to create a dataframe with all fighters and their atributes. It is currently in order of most recent fight back to the start of the promotion.

I want to remove all occurances of each fighter other than their most recent.

e.g.

```
index, fighter, height, age, wins, losses
0, mcgregor, 165, 31, 14,5
1, porier, 165, 30, 21, 6
2, Ferguson, 180, 38, 28, 4
3, mcgregor, 165, 30, 14, 4 <- remove this row.
```

thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2):

You can sort by age (highest on top) and `drop_duplicates`:

```
df.sort_values(by='age', ascending=False).drop_duplicates(subset='fighter')
```